# Why does :+ appending to a Seq have no effect?

Tags: scala, sequence, seq

i wanna have a result-Sequence with a Triple of (String, Int, Int) like this:

```
var all_info: Seq[(String, Int, Int)] = null
```

now that i try adding elements to my Seq as followed:

```
  if (all_info == null) {
    all_info = Seq((name, id, count))
  } else {
    all_info :+ (name, id, count)
  }
```

and print them

```
    Console.println(all_info.mkString)
```

Unfortunately, the printed result is only the first triple that is added by the if-clause and basically intializes a new Seq, since it's been just "null" before. 
All following triples which are supposed to be added to the Seq in the else-clause are not.
I also tried different methods like "++" which won't work either ("too many arguments")

Can't really figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks for any help in advance!
Greetings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all instead of using `null`s you would be better using an empty collection. Next use :+= so the result of :+ **would not be thrown away** — :+ produces a new collection as the result instead of modifying the existing one. The final code would look like

```
var all_info: Seq[(String, Int, Int)] = Seq.empty
all_info :+= (name, id, count)
```

As you can see, now you don't need `if`s and code should work fine.

Comment: Weird, in the library it's: :+ = A copy of this sequence with an element appended. So i thought it would just append the new triple to the existing result and there wasn't even a ":+=". Anyway, the code works fine and i learned about a new operator, thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Method `:+` creates new collection and leaves your original collection untouched.

You should use method `+=`. If there is no method `+=` in `all_info` compiler will treat `all_info += (name, id, count)` as `all_info = all_info + (name, id, count)`.

On the contrary, if you'll change the type of `all_info` to some mutable collection, you'll get method `+=` in it, so your code will work as expected: method `+=` on mutable collections changes target collection.

Note that there is no method `:+=` in [mutable collections](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.generic.Growable), so you'll get `all_info = all_info :+ (name, id, count)` even for mutable collection.